# How should I store update history (auditing)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am wondering how to properly store object update information (ie auditing). My constraints are:

- I have 1 type of objects with 10-25 properties that will be updated: These properties are well defined.
- Each property is expected to be updated hundred to hundred thousand times over the life of the object (a hard limit can be set if needed).
- The number of objects cannot be limited.
- Most accesses will only read the last 100 updates.

My purist instinct want's me to put all updates in a table (per property). I can then query + merge the results to get my history. Trying to keep it in normal form as much as possible.

On the other hand I'd like to keep updates close to their parent object (I will *never* mix updates from 2 objects). This would make it easier to shard (keeping updates and objects on the same machine).

Comment: Do the properties usually get updated at the same time for each object, or at different times?  That is, do you update 10 properties at once for an object, or only one?

Comment: At different time